# How can I start datatable at another page after ajax request success?

Tags: ajax, datatables, draw

This is my datatable:

```
var table = $('.table').DataTable({
     "serverSide": true,
     "ajax": '{{ path('json') }}',
});
```

On an ajax request success, I would like to start at another page:

```
  $.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    data: {
      "id": id,
    },
    url:'{{ path('json') }}',
    success : function (data) {
      table.displayStart( 20 ).draw();
    }
  });
```

But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [page()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page()) function.

```
table.page(20).draw('page');
```